# dplyr Auto-disconnecting postgres connection issue

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

I am using dplyr package to connect to PostgreSQL, and my code is as below:

```
# Connect to local PostgreSQL via dplyr
library('dplyr')
localdb <- src_postgres(dbname = 'postgres',
                                                 host = 'localhost',
                                                 port = 5432,
                                                 user = 'postgres',
                                                 password = '236236')

#Write table from R to PostgreSQL
iris<-as.data.frame(iris)
dbWriteTable(localdb$con,'iris',iris, row.names=FALSE)
```

The connection is successful, but after about 5 minutes, a message popped up, saying `"Auto-disconnecting postgres connection (4308, 1)"`. I am not sure how this issue comes from, and I need to deal with large data which takes more than 5 minutes to write to PostgreSQL, so I want to know how to solve this auto-disconnecting issue.

Comment: don't you want db_write_table() not dbWriteTable?

Comment: dbWriteTable works fine in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with `src_sqlite()`. The error that I got was `Auto-disconnecting SQLiteConnection`. Apparently, the usage of the src_* functions is now discouraged (from the documentation of `tbl()`).

> However, modern best practice is to use tbl() directly on an DBIConnection.

Before I was using the code below. The code in itself didn't return any errors. However, after using the same db again, I would get the error `Auto-disconnecting SQLiteConnection`.

```
path <- 'C:/sql.db'
sql_data <- src_sqlite(path)
# work on the sql_data variable
tbl(sql_data)
DBI::dbDisconnect(thesql$con)
```

As already said, the usage of src_sqlite is discouraged. Using the preferred code below solved my issue.

```
sql_data <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = path)
# work on the sql_data variable
tbl(sql_data)
DBI::dbDisconnect(thesql)
```

Pay attention that the disconnect statement slightly changed and that the SQLite() arguments are in fact dbConnect() arguments.